# Skype doesn't start on Ubuntu 12.04 x64

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, skype

I'm working on Ubuntu 12.04 x64 and when I'm trying to run Skype there's following message in terminal: `skype: error while loading shared libraries: libgstbase-0.10.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
I've tried reinstalling and purging but it doesn't work.  
 Can anyone explain what is wrong and what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The .so file that exists but was reported as "doesn't exist" because it was incompatible with the system architecture. It was a 32 bit version, but you have a 64 bit operating system. According to the documentation on the Skype website, there is a simple solution.

Open a terminal (ctrl + alt + t) and run

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
apt-get -f install skype
```

[Source](http://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/64-bit-linux-version/td-p/991578)

Comment: Thank you for reply but it seems like my dpkg doesn't have this option: `dpkg: error: unknown option --add-architecture`

Comment: This didn't work for me. I still get the same error on opening Skype. I notice that at no point did my problematic shared lib (libsqlite3.so.0) get reinstalled. I removed skype and reinstalled, same thing. I cannot "apt-get remove libsqlite3.so.0", it says "you have
requested an impossible situation ... unmet dependencies.
 libatk-wrapper-java : Depends: default-jre ..."